# How to make swf file including other resources to a application bundle in osx?

Tags: macos, flash, bundle

I'm new to Mac OS X, so these questions may seem to be stupid.
I have googled for nearly half a day, but can't find the exact answers.

**About applications on Mac OS X:**

1. Does any application must be placed in the /Applications folder to execute it?
2. If not, how does Mac OS know what applications I have installed and show them all in the Launch Panel?
3. What should I do to install an "nake" foo.app ?

**Is this possible and how to implement it? or any other suggestions?**

I downloaded the "Flash Player.app" from Adobe's site, and got a .swf file and some other resource files that will be loaded by the .swf file.
I want to bundle the "Flash Player.app" and the swf file including its resource files together to form an MySwf.app using AppleScript. So that the .swf file can be opened on any other Mac without the "Flash Player.app" having to be installed.

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I have tried to answer your question as well as I can. I don't think this is an actual programmer's question. You're asking for something a programmer normally wouldn't ask, because Flash is installed by the user. You might even violate licenses if you distribute your solution including parts of Flash (I am not sure). So, what is it that you really want to do and why? Try to ask a slightly more technical question.

Comment: I had thought whether this question was more suitable for Stack Overflow or Super User. Finally I put it here because this has something to with how does a AS programmer distribute his apps on Mac OS. I downloaded an .dmg installer which includes only an standalone "Flash Player.app" from Adobe. It is said to be a standalone flash projector. So I don't think there would be any other procedure except extracting it from the .dmg needed to install it. Besides, I think we can publish our .swf file with a "Flash Player.app" as long as the flash player can be downloaded freely.

Comment: What I want is just really simple, namely giving a game program making with flash and Action Script to someone whose Mac haven't got a Flash Player installed on it. Then the guy can double click some file to play the game without having to download and install the Flash Player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the Flash installer to make the Flash Player work. Flash gets disabled every now and then. So, you will have to rely on the user to install and update flash. It doesn't make sense to install Flash Player.app only.

Applications don't need to be installed in /Applications to be executable. You can execute them from anywhere, as long as the file has the necessary permissions.

When an .app package is written to disk, Mac OS X recognises this and updates the desktop files using the bundle identifier that is in the package. THat's how OSX knows which app to use to open a particular file.

Apps don't get added to the launch panel automatically. Their installers have to take care of this. You can add apps to the launch panel manually.

Answer (score 2):

My final resolution:
**run.app**, compiles from an AppleScript whose content is as follow:

```
set myPath to path to me  
tell application "Finder"  
    set folderPath to container of myPath as string  
    open (folderPath & "Source:minigame.swf") using (folderPath & "Source:Flash Player.app")  
end tell
```

**Source** folder which contains **Flash Player.app** and **minigame.swf**.
When I zip them and give the zip archive to other guy, he just need to unzip it and double click the run.app before opening the **minigame.swf**.
At first, I tried to put both **Flash Player.app** and **minigame.swf** in the run.app bundle which was unfortunately failed. There may be some 'tricks' I don't know yet...